# How to switch to different python function on button clicks with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

here is my `<form>` in *index.html*

```
<!-- inputs/outputs -->
      <form action="{{ url_for('predict1')}}" method="post">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div><textarea name="message" id="newitem" rows="3" cols="150" class="form-control"
              required="required"></textarea></div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Generate">
      </form>
      <h3 style="color : red; font-weight: bold; font-size: 30px;" id="predh3">{{ prediction_text }}</h3>
<!-- inputs/outputs -->
```

from here I am calling a **predict1** function which gives the output in **prediction_text** variable.

This is the **predict** function in *app.py*

```
@app.route('/predict',methods=['post'])
def predict1():
   ''' some work '''
   return render_template("index.html",prediction_text = output_var)

def predict2():
   ''' some work '''
   return render_template("index.html",prediction_text = output_var)
```

here is the jQuery in *index.html*.

```
$('textarea#newitem').keyup(function (e) {
    var code = e.which;
    if (code == 16) {     // shift 16 to call predict1()
      e.preventDefault();
      $('h3#predh3').append(e.target.value);
    }
  });
  $('textarea#newitem').keyup(function (e) {
    var code = e.which;
    if (code == 13) {     //Enter 13 for call predict2()
      e.preventDefault();
      $('h3#predh3').append(e.target.value);
    }
});
```

jQuery bounded by `<script>` and `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

So my question is I want to call **predict1()** function after typing something in the forms `<textarea>` by hitting ***shift*** key which will give me an outcome and want to call **predict2()** function in the same way but here by hitting ***enter*** key.
I started learning HTML, CSS, JS last week so any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking to update is the `action` attribute on the `<form>` element.  Start by telling JavaScript what the two values can be.  In your JavaScript code, you can have something like this:

```
var predict1URL = "{{ url_for('predict1')}}";
var predict2URL = "{{ url_for('predict2')}}";
```

This would render to the actual URLs in the JavaScript code.  For example:

```
var predict1URL = "/path/to/predict1";
var predict2URL = "/path/to/predict2";
```

Once you have those, within your `keyup` handlers (side note: you only need one handler, they're both attached to the same element) just set the property on the `<form>`.  Which might look like this (assuming there's only one `<form>`):

```
$('textarea#newitem').keyup(function (e) {
    var code = e.which;
    if (code == 16) {     // shift 16 to call predict1()
        e.preventDefault();
        $('h3#predh3').append(e.target.value);
        $('form').prop('action', predict1URL);
    } else if (code == 13) {     //Enter 13 for call predict2()
        e.preventDefault();
        $('h3#predh3').append(e.target.value);
        $('form').prop('action', predict2URL);
    }
});
```

If there's more than one `<form>` then you can make use of an `id` in the element and the jQuery selector(s) just like you already do in your other selectors.

Comment: Thank you so much let me try this & will let you know. :D